# What constitutes 'array access' in the context of algorithms?

Tags: java, algorithm, radix-sort

Below is an LSD Radix sort implementation in Java from a textbook to sort an array of strings where each string contains exactly `W` characters.

I want to count the number of array accesses during runtime. I've read that LSD sort is supposed to require `n * c` array accesses where `n` is the number of strings and `c` the amount of characters in each string. However, the algorithm below accesses more than one array several times. If I increment a counter at each of these I'll end up with a significant factor of `nc`.

So what exactly constitutes 'array access' in the context of algorithms? Is there only one instance of array access that is considered more significant that I should count here, or is this example in fact an inefficient implementation that uses more array access than necessary?

```
 public int lsdSort(String[] array, int W) {
  int access = 0;
  // Sort a[] on leading W characters.
  int N = array.length;
  String[] aux = new String[N];
  for (int d = W-1; d >= 0; d--)
  { // Sort by key-indexed counting on dth char.
    int[] count = new int[R+1]; // Compute frequency counts.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        count[array[i].charAt(d) + 1]++;
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
        // Transform counts to indices.
        count[r+1] += count[r];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // Distribute.
        aux[count[array[i].charAt(d)]++] = array[i];

    }  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // Copy back.
        array[i] = aux[i];
  }

  return access;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks to Yuval for the small edits that improved readability!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I've read that LSD sort is supposed to require n times c array accesses where n is the number of strings and c the amount of characters in each string.

Are you sure you haven't read that it's `O(nc)`? That's not the same thing at all. It's [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). The point isn't to determine the exact number of array accesses - it's to talk about how it grows (or rather, the *limit* of how it can grow) as `n` or `c` increase. In this case it increases linearly - if you increase `n` by a factor of 1000, you would only expect the total cost to grow by a factor of 1000 too... whereas if it were an O(n<sup>2</sup>c) algorithm instead, it might grow by a factor of 1,000,000. (Strictly speaking any O(nc) algorithm *is also* O(n<sup>2</sup>c) due to it only being a limit, but let's not get into that.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to make sense. I have only recently started studying algorithms and I'm familiar with the big-O notation. My textbook however makes it seem as if Radix sort is supposed to only need exactly `c` array accesses for each string `n` despite offering this implementation example, which confused me.

Comment: Though I don't really see any reason why `nc` shouldn't be doable. You just need `c` loops iterating through the array and putting values into the helper array. Well ok you can argue that's `2nc` as we have to write the characters back, but different array ;-)

Comment: @Parusa: It's possible that that's really what it means, and it really is possible. It seems less *interesting* than the big-O bit though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I guess the book is simply trying to tell me (albeit in a confusing manner) that Radix sorts can sort in linear time, and that it actually *can* do this in strictly c.n, but that actual efficiency depends on the implementation. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

All the array accesses inside the first for loop are essentially counted as a combined number of array accesses, so that's your c. The n is how many times you do these combined array accesses. This gives you an approximate idea of the growth of the function, not the actual count of accesses.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int lsdSort(String[] array, int W) {
  int access = 0;
  // Sort a[] on leading W characters.
  int N = array.length;
  String[] aux = new String[N];
  for (int d = W-1; d >= 0; d--)
  { // Sort by key-indexed counting on dth char.
    int[] count = new int[R+1]; // Compute frequency counts.
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        count[array[i].charAt(d) + 1]++;
        access++;
        access++;
    }
    for (int r = 0; r < R; r++) {
        // Transform counts to indices.
        count[r+1] += count[r];
        access++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        // Distribute.
        aux[count[array[i].charAt(d)]++] = array[i];
        access++; 
        access++;
        access++;   
    }  
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) // Copy back.
        array[i] = aux[i];
        access++;
        access++;
  }

  return access;

  }
```

an array 'access' is either a read or a write...

Comment: +1 for the example. I hadn't considered incrementing several times within the same loop. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

In [Big-O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) asymptotic notation, the number of access are proportional to a constant. When you analyze the code, all the constants are discarded.

In the case of Radix Sort the Big O is `O(cn)`. But if you want to actually count how many times the array is accessed you need to multiply that number for some constant `k`, where that `k` is specific to the concrete coded implementation.

For example, this function is `O(n)` but the number of times the array is accessed is `2n`: one for reading the value, and one for updating it. The number `2` is discarded.

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
   A[i] = A[i] + 1;
```