# Why is this N3 array accesses?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

My algorithms textbook by By Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne said this for loop has 3N array accesses, and elsewhere I found the same code for this loop on some slides for a class claiming its 5N. It looks like 4N to me because a[i] is used twice.

What is it and why is it that?

Third for loop in algorithm

```
// Distribute the records.
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
  aux[count[a[i].key()]++] = a[i];
```

Link to article of sedgewick. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2180073

Link to Class slides from allegheny college. http://cs.allegheny.edu/sites/jwenskovitch/teaching/CMPSC250/docs/lectures/14%20String%20Sorts.pdf

link to past stack overflow. [What constitutes 'array access' in the context of algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923230/what-constitutes-array-access-in-the-context-of-algorithms)

Comment: Any decent compiler will generate only one access for `a[i]`.

Comment: if [] doesn't have side effects, a[i] can be computed once and used twice (1 access). then count + aux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a[i] is loaded twice, +2.
count[...] is incremented once, which means a load and a store, +2.
aux[...] is written once, which means a store, +1.

2+2+1=5

I would say it is 5N, but trivially optimizable to 4N by caching a[i] in a variable. It is 4N optimizable to 3N if we count the increment as a single access. AFAIK, there is no universal convention regarding whether incrementing a cell of an array is a single access or two accesses.

Modern CPUs typically don't care about arrays. All memory is treated uniformly. Frequently (atomic) increment operations are provide that work on memory. I would say 4N myself, but probably for a different reason than OP.

Comment: Thank you, to you and the commenters. I'd up-vote if I could. I'm also surprised how fast that was.